# Dúvida de sintaxe no AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sintaxe

Estou iniciando no Angular e em alguns casos vi que se passa parâmetros no colchete do "module" e em outros casos na "function", sendo que na função já vi 2 formas de declaração.

Exemplo Module:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ui.utils.masks', 'ngCordova', 'angular-md5', 'ngMessages', 'angularSoap'])
```

Exemplo Function 1:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider){...}

.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $pouchDB){...}
```

Exemplo Function 2:

```
.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope, $any', function($scope, $any){...}
```

Alguém poderia me explicar:

- Qual a diferença entre a declaração da Function 1 e Function 2 (por que existe essas 2 formas e qual seria o impacto na prática em escolher uma ou outra)?
- Qual a diferença entre passar esses parametros no module e nas functions?

  - Tem alguma ligação entre eles?
- O que se passa e o que se pode passar nesses parametros

Não se prendam somente às minhas perguntas. Quanto mais informação, melhor, mas a princípio minhas dúvidas são essas acima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Qual a diferença entre a declaração da Function 1 e Function 2 (por que existe essas 2 formas e qual seria o impacto na prática em escolher uma ou outra)?

Quando é usado a minificação de arquivos JavaScript, os nomes dos parâmetros são alterados para nomes mais curtos $scope => a. Quando habilitada a função mangle, deve ser usado `['$scope',function($scope){}]` nesse formato, para o Angular reconhecer o parâmetro a ser injetado no controller.

- Qual a diferença entre passar esses parametros no module e nas functions?
  Tem alguma ligação entre eles?

Os parâmetros no module, são exatamente quais dependências externas o modulo deve carregar.
Ex.: `app.module('myApp',['ngResource']).controller('AppCtrl',['$scope','$resource',function($scope, $resource))`

No Exemplo acima eu carrego o modulo ngResource para poder usar nos meus controllers.

Qualquer dúvida, só falar.